# DNS name of virtual machine

Tags: network, vmware, dns, virtualization

I need to reliably access the SqlServer running on my Windows 7 VM. I've tried setting a static ip and reserving that ip for the machine in VMWare's Nat config but that cuts off WAN access from the VM. Right now I am just editing my database url every time I restart the VM. Does anyone have a complete set of instructions on how to configure an internal NAT static IP in VMWare Fusion 5.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to manually edit VMware's network preferences and add static hosts to get this working. The file necessary can be found at `/Library/Application Support/VMware Fusion/vmnet8/dhcpd.conf`. The file is read-only so `chmod` it writeable first.

For each static host you'll have to add the following and change the hostname, MAC address and IP to your VMs:

```
host yourhosthere {
    hardware ethernet 11:22:33:44:55:66;
    fixed-address 192.168.87.100;
}
```

I'd recommend selecting the IP from outside the DHCP range, which is defined in the same file on the row starting with `range`.

After this you have to restart VMware services with `sudo "/Library/Application Support/VMware Fusion/boot.sh" --restart`

As for the DNS name, after you have a static IP you can add it to your `/etc/hosts` file using the following syntax:

```
192.168.87.100 yourhosthere
```

Comment: This worked for me with yourhosthere=the host name from the operating system not the VMWare name of the machine. Some of the paths are different in Mavericks. Thanks